# Slack Dialog.open not Opening if Variable is in Title

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

Whenever I try to add a variable to my dialog title, dialog.open does not work and no errors are thrown.

If I remove the variable from the title everything works fine, it is only when I add the variable to the title

I execute this before I define dialog

```
app.post('/create', function(req, res) {
  var users = []
  var {
    text, trigger_id
  } = req.body;
  text = text.toUpperCase()
  var issuetypes = []
  axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: baseURL + 'project/' + text
  }).then(function(response) {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.issueTypes.length; i++) {
      issuetypes.push({
        label: response.data.issueTypes[i].name,
        value: response.data.issueTypes[i].name
      });
    }
```

Does not work:

```
const dialog = {
      token: botToken,
      trigger_id,
      dialog: JSON.stringify({
        title: 'Create a new ' + text + ' Ticket',
        callback_id: 'submit-ticket',
        submit_label: 'Submit',
        elements: [{
          label: 'Project',
          type: 'text',
          name: 'project'
        }, {
          label: 'Summary',
          type: 'text',
          name: 'summary',
        }, {
          label: 'Description',
          type: 'textarea',
          name: 'description',
          optional: true,
        }, {
          label: 'Type',
          type: 'select',
          name: 'type',
          options: issuetypes,
        }, {
          label: 'Reporter',
          type: 'select',
          name: 'reporter',
          optional: true,
          options: [{
            label: 'Reporter',
            value: 'reporter'
          }, ],
        }, {
          label: 'Link',
          type: 'select',
          name: 'epic',
          optional: true,
          options: [{
            label: 'Epic',
            value: 'epic'
          }, ],
        }, ],
      }),
    };
```

Works:

```
const dialog = {
      token: botToken,
      trigger_id,
      dialog: JSON.stringify({
        title: 'Create a new Ticket',
        callback_id: 'submit-ticket',
        submit_label: 'Submit',
        elements: [{
          label: 'Project',
          type: 'text',
          name: 'project'
        }, {
          label: 'Summary',
          type: 'text',
          name: 'summary',
        }, {
          label: 'Description',
          type: 'textarea',
          name: 'description',
          optional: true,
        }, {
          label: 'Type',
          type: 'select',
          name: 'type',
          options: issuetypes,
        }, {
          label: 'Reporter',
          type: 'select',
          name: 'reporter',
          optional: true,
          options: [{
            label: 'Reporter',
            value: 'reporter'
          }, ],
        }, {
          label: 'Link',
          type: 'select',
          name: 'epic',
          optional: true,
          options: [{
            label: 'Epic',
            value: 'epic'
          }, ],
        }, ],
      }),
    };
```

Then I call dialog.open

```
axios.post("https://slack.com/api/dialog.open", qs.stringify(dialog))
      .then(
        (result) => {
          res.send('');
        }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
      })
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  })
});
```

Any ideas as to why dialog.open does not work?

Comment: That is weird. Can you please add the content of the text variable to your post?

Comment: @ErikKalkoken, the text variable is always a 4-6 letter code which I convert to UpperCase. I just updated my question with more code describing everything that happens before I create dialog.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe your title is too long. You only got 24 chars and the text alone is already 19 chars. With spaces that leaves max 3 chars for your ticket number. Try shorten the title. See here: https://api.slack.com/dialogs#top-level_dialog_attributes

Comment: @ErikKalkoken, the title was to long, I did not realize the title length was capped and 24. I thought if length was capped it would be 50.

Comment: cool. So I does it works now? Happy to post this as answer so we can close this question with a solution

Comment: @ErikKalkoken, yep it works, still wierd Slack doesn't throw an error of some kind...

Comment: awesome. and you are right. There should be a validation error according to the docs. So I guess there must be another reason why you are not receiving it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the Dialog is not shown when you have the variable in the title is that you exceed the maximum length of 24 chars for a title. (see [here](https://api.slack.com/dialogs#top-level_dialog_attributes) for reference)

You should however received the validation error from the API though as documented for the [`dialog.open`](https://api.slack.com/methods/dialog.open) method:

```
"The field `title` cannot be longer than 24 characters"
```

There must be another reason why you are not receiving it.